# creating a dynamic ul with two columns with Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to create a grid with two columns with a set rows. Reading the documentation this should work...

```
 <div class="grid grid-cols-2 row-span-3 gap-8" v-for="topic in course?.course_details.topics">
   <ul>
      <li>{{ topic }}</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

However, the output is one column.

Example:

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think what you need is to put `v-for` loop on `li` element and relocate classes from `div` to `ul` (div can be removed). Right now you create 5 divs with two columns each (first column - list with only one `li` element, second column is empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to wrap the `v-for` element, so that each element in the loop is inside the grid layout:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      course: {
        course_details: {
          topics: [
            'foo',
            'bar',
            'baz',
          ],
        },
      },
    };
  },
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.3.4/vue.global.prod.min.js" integrity="sha512-39BSQXI5q1XlvVhLfFRidKG8KM6Tr6VS/XSnNo6N/A0ZXexHCeoUI/s+ulujQy3UREjoLNrMnFat8VI0mMugWA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2 row-span-3 gap-8">
    <div v-for="topic in course?.course_details.topics">
      <ul>
        <li>{{ topic }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `v-for` directive to the `<li>` elements instead. This should work:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 row-span-3 gap-8">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="topic in course?.course_details.topics">{{ topic }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```